# Obfuscating control words and control symbols

Tags: obfuscation, rtf

I wonder is it possible to obfuscate control words in RTF standard? For example instead \objemb it will be something like \%6F%62%6A%65%6D%62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. We can use unix representation to obfuscate control words.

For example 
 **{*\o\'62jdata** is the same **{*\objdata**

Instead letter **b** we put the same but in unix representation **\'62**

Here 62 - is HEX value of char b.

Answer (score 0):

The [RTF Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=10725) suggests that this is not possible:

> A control word is defined by: \<ASCII Letter Sequence><Delimiter>
>   where <Delimiter> marks the end of the control word’s name

It then goes on to say:

> The <ASCII Letter Sequence> is made up of ASCII alphabetical characters (a through z and A through Z).

The reference parser implementation at the end of the specification  follows this definition, and doesn't have any scope for dealing with escaped characters.

Comment: it is possible. @JonIles you may see my answer